# How to send the Mongo collection with key value pair in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want return the mongo collection with key value pair like bellow

```
{
  "message":"Success",
  "Success":1,
  "data":{"key","value"}
}
```

I am using bellow code to return the document

```
try
{                
    dynamic jObj = JObject.FromObject(val);
    var Collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Registeration");
    string id = jObj._id;
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId(id));
    var doc = Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
    if(doc != null)
    {                   
        return doc.ToJson();
    }
    else
    {
        return doc.Add("Success","0").Add("Mesaage","No Data Found").ToJson();
    }
}
catch(Exception exp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exp.StackTrace);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change my mode like this

```
 if(doc != null)
 {      
   var t = new BsonDocument();
   t.Add("Success","1").Add("data",doc);
   return t.ToJson();
  }
```

Now it's working with expected output.
Thank you...